# File Watcher with Flutter Framework

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to implement file watcher library "https://pub.dev/packages/watcher" in my project, for Android and iOS Devices. How can i implement this library?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to monitor files modification and new addition in folder of Android or iOS device storage with the help of this watcher package.

Answer (score 0):

This library has very poor documentation unfortunately, but there's an example at least:

[example/watch.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/watcher/blob/master/example/watch.dart)

```dart
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
import 'package:watcher/watcher.dart';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  if (arguments.length != 1) {
    print('Usage: watch <directory path>');
    return;
  }

  var watcher = DirectoryWatcher(p.absolute(arguments[0]));
  watcher.events.listen((event) {
    print(event);
  });
}
```

For more details you need to look at the [API Docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/watcher/latest/watcher/FileWatcher-class.html).

PS. you probably mean you want to **use** this library, not **implement** it.

Comment: It seems to depend on `dart:io` which should work on mobile. https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Comment: It's need to monitor to the file changing's in folder.